# Multiple async methods that access a single ObservableCollection in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight-4.0, asynchronous, thread-safety, webclient, observablecollection

In a Silverlight app I need to download a large amount of files. When a file finished downloading I need to update an ObservableCollection object. This is the code I am using :

```cs
private void downloadFiles(List<string> files)
{
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        string _file = file;

        new WebClient().OpenReadTaskAsync(new Uri(_file)).ContinueWith(t1 =>
        {
            Stream stream = t1.Result;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)stream.Length).ContinueWith(t2 =>
            {
                myObservableCollection.Add(_file); //An Exception is thrown.                       
            });
        });
    }
}
```

When trying to add to myObservableCollection An exception is thrown:
Cannot change ObservableCollection during a CollectionChanged or PropertyChanged event.

One way to fix that is to await on each OpenReadTaskAsync, but then I won't be maximizing the  I/O. I also came across a ReaderWriterLock which look like it can help, but unfortunately it's not avaible in Silverlight.

How can I handle this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could serialize updating the `ObservableCollection` on the UI thread using this:

```
string _file = file;
var ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

...

.ContinueWith(t2 =>
    {
        myObservableCollection.Add(_file); //An Exception is thrown.                       
    }
    ,  ui );
```